# Setting visibility to GONE does not hide the imageView

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

As shown below in the below posted layout. there is an ImageView with is "cardViewImageViewRight". when I set the visibility of this view to GONE, I expect the entire space. This imageView occupies will disappear. But what happens is, when I set the visibility to GONE, only the image itself disappears but still the view occupies the same space.

Why when I set the visibility to GONE, only the image disappears and space occupied by the imageView still there?

**Code**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
cardview:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
cardview:cardElevation="3dp"
cardview:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:weightSum="6">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cardViewImageViewLeft"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="6">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cardViewTextViewName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:text="Name: " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cardViewTextViewDate"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="18.08.2019" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardViewTextViewDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Description Description Description Description" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="7">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cardViewTextViewPriceLabel"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Price: " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cardViewTextViewPrice"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="299.999 " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cardViewTextViewCurrency"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Eur" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="end">

                <RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/cardViewRatingBar"
                    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:numStars="5"
                    android:rating="3"
                    android:stepSize=".5" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cardViewImageViewRight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Note**:

As shown in the above mentioned layout, I have two imageviews, on on the right and another on on the left. When I set the visibility of the on on the left to GONE, the entire imageview disappear, that's what I want. But when I do the same thing to the imageView on the right, however, as mentioned above in my question, only the image disappears but the view of the imageview itsef is still there.

And both the right and the left imageviews, belong to the same parent linearlayout, the one that contains weight_sum=6.

Comment: Feedback: I think you're asking too many questions, possibly because you've found that it's easier to post a question than do the necessary amount of research on each thing. In the last two days, you've asked six questions, there were four questions on 13th August alone, and 31st July saw five questions on the same day. This is a pattern of a lack of research, in my view, and I say that to help you.

Comment: Then, for each question, there is a lot of all-lower-case writing and/or a lack of spell-checking, which then results in a disproportionate need for volunteer editors to make repairs for the benefit of future readers. The sum of this is that if you could ask fewer questions, and put more prior effort into research, and also put more effort into the posting/construction of each question, then we will obtain mutual long-term benefits, which is that you'll learn to be more self-sufficient, and volunteer editors will have less work to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have given weights 1, 4, 1 to the views, changing the visibility to `gone` has no effect.  
 The problem is the weights you have assigned.   
When you set the visibility to GONE to the left image then the middle layout comes and takes its position but still its width is the same as before. When you set the visibility to GONE to the right image there is nothing to take its place, so you must change by code the weight of the middle layout.  
Give an id to the layout left:  `android:id="@+id/linearLayout"`  
Then get it by `findViewById`:   
`LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);`     
and finally change it's weight to 5:

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) linearLayout.getLayoutParams(); 
    params.weight = 5f;
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: please have a look again at my question. i added section titled NOTE

Comment: @LetsamrIt I did see the NOTE. You must understand that the problem is the weights you have assigned. When you set the visibility to GONE to the left image then the middle layout comes and takes its position but still its width is the same as before. When you set the visibility to GONE to the right image there is nothing to take its place, so you must change by code the weight of the middle layout.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the visibility of LinearLayout to GONE in order to dissolve the view properly along with imageview , LinearLayout is occupying the space

Comment: please have a look again at my question. i added section titled NOTE